# ¿Cómo ingresar datos dentro de un arreglo ya inicializado?

Tags: c++, array, funciones, function

He estado programando en C++ y con los arreglos me ha surgido una duda, ¿de qué forma se podrán ingresar datos dentro del arreglo de la función?, si el arreglo ya esta definido como int en la entrada de la función. He intentado lo que sale en el código mas abajo y dejarlo vacío como arr[] pero tampoco funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

```
void Datos(int arr[5]) {
arr[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };//esto me tira error
}
int main(){
   int arreglo[5];
   Datos(arreglo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás teniendo una desafortunada y terrible confusión de conceptos. Esta línea:

```
arr[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
```

No significa "*Asigna al arreglo de 5 elementos los siguientes cinco valores*" si no que significa "**Asigna al sexto elemento del arreglo esta lista de cinco valores**". Lo cuál es incorrecto porque un arreglo de cinco elementos no tiene seis (al indexar desde `0` el elemento `5` es el sexto) y porque un entero no puede contener una lista de enteros.

Posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
int indice = 0;

for (auto valor : { 1,2,3,4,5 })
    arr[indice++] = valor;
```

Pero eso no te cambiará los valores del arreglo que recibes por parámetros porque el arreglo lo recibes por copia, para poder modificarlo en la función debes pasarlo por referencia:

```
void Datos(int (&arr)[5]) {
//         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Referencia a arreglo de cinco enteros
    for (auto valor : { 1,2,3,4,5 })
        arr[indice++] = valor;
}
```

Si te parece confusa la notación de referencia a arreglo: (`tipo (&nombre)[cantidad de elementos]`) puedes hacer un alias:

```
using CincoInt = int[5];

void Datos (CincoInt &arr) {
    for (auto valor : { 1,2,3,4,5 })
        arr[indice++] = valor;
}
```